# Warning for Missing Virtual Keyword

Tags: c++, g++

I had a frustrating problem recently that boiled down to a very simple coding mistake.  Consider the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    void func() { std::cout << "BASE" << std::endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void func() { std::cout << "DERIVED" << std::endl; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Base* obj = new Derived;
    obj->func();
    delete obj;

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

> BASE

Obviously (for this case), I meant to put the virtual keyword on Base::func so that Derived::func would be called in main.  I realize this is (probably) allowed by the c++ standard, and possibly with good reason, but it seems to me that 99% of the time this would be a coding mistake.  However, when I compiled using g++ and all the -Wblah options I could think of, no warnings were generated.

Is there a way to generate a warning when both a base and derived class have member functions of the same name where the derived class's function is virtual and the base class's function is not?

Comment: `delete` in the example cannot destruct `Derived` because `Base` does not have a `virtual` destructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Visual C++ you can use the `override` extension.  Like this:

```
virtual void func() override { std::cout << "DERIVED" << std::endl; }
```

This will give an error if the function doesn't actually override a base class method.  I use this for ALL virtual functions.  Typically I define a macro like this:

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
#define OVERRIDE override
#else
#define OVERRIDE
#endif
```

So I can use it like this:

```
virtual void func() OVERRIDE { std::cout << "DERIVED" << std::endl; }
```

I've looked for something like this in g++ but couldn't find a similar concept.

The only thing I dislike about it in Visual C++ is that you can't have the compiler require it (or at least warn) on all overridden functions.

Comment: I use this as well.  It's also handy when someone changes the signature of a function (adding a parameter, etc.) but fails to update the base or derived counterpart(s).  Normally the virtual-ness would silently stop working, but this trick makes the compiler generate an error.

Comment: Great!  I didn't know about this extension.  I'll probably use this for my own projects since I use Visual Studio, but for this particular project I'll have to stick to g++ :(

Comment: please note that `override` is in c++11, so that will work with recent gcc and clang in c++11 mode (`-std=c++11`)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any g++ flag to produce a warning on this (not to say there isn't one), but I'd say this is a pretty rare error. Most people write the base class first, as an interface using pure virtual functions. If you had said:

```
void func() = 0;
```

then you would get a syntax error.

Answer (score 1):

man gcc

-Woverloaded-virtual (C++ and Objective-C++ only)
       Warn when a function declaration hides virtual functions from a base class.  For example, in:

```
           struct A {
             virtual void f();
           };

           struct B: public A {
             void f(int);
           };

   the "A" class version of "f" is hidden in "B", and code like:

           B* b;
           b->f();

   will fail to compile.
```

Comment: Using this option doesn't warn in the code posted above.  In this case Foo::func isn't virtual (which is a prerequisite of the warning), and even if it was it still wouldn't trigger the warning because Bar::func matches the correct signature.  If I made Foo::func virtual AND changed Bar::func's signature (i.e. func(int)) only then does the warning trigger.  In my case I am overriding a NON-virtual function of Foo, which means if I have a Foo* then the Foo implementation will be called, and not the Bar implementation.  However, only if I have a Bar* will the Bar implementation be called.